# Unable to view Xamarin.IOS Storyboard

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

When opening a Storyboard in Xamarin.IOS it gives the following error.

[image]

***Source Code:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="6211" systemVersion="14A298i" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES">
  <dependencies>
    <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="6204" />
  </dependencies>
  <scenes />
</document>
```

Comment: At the error indicates, there is a version mismatch, have you tried opening it in Xcode to see if it can be upgraded to the Xcode/Xamarin.iOS version that you are currently using?

Comment: @SushiHangover ok i will try this is new to me

Comment: @SushiHangover that worked thanx :)

Comment: Glad it worked... 